# NameError: name 'model_object' is not defined

Tags: django, logentries

I'm trying to get all model operations in my django app with the following code but it returns an error.
I get the error

```
NameError: name 'model_object' is not defined

def admin_main(request):
    logs = LogEntry.objects.log_action(
        user_id=request.user.id,
        content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model_object).pk,
        object_repr=unicode(obj),
        object_id=obj.id,
        message="",
        action_flag=ADDITION if create else DELETION)

    logs = logs.order_by('-action_time')[:40]
    return render(request,'history.html', {"logs":logs})
```

Comment: you need to define the **model_object** variable

Comment: what is **model_object** ???

Comment: @rahul.m. How and where??

Comment: for which model do you need to add this ?

Comment: @rahul.m. I intend to use it in about 4 models.

Comment: @rahul.m. Set me up assuming I had a model like User. How would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from app.models import MyModel1  # 1st import your model

def admin_main(request):
    logs = LogEntry.objects.log_action(
        user_id=request.user.id,
        content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel1).pk,
        object_repr=unicode(obj),
        object_id=obj.id,
        message="",
        action_flag=ADDITION if create else DELETION)

    logs = logs.order_by('-action_time')[:40]
    return render(request,'history.html', {"logs":logs})

# e.g from doc
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
<ContentType: user>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager

Comment: obj not defined